# 50 volts on hot to neutral but 120 volts with wall switch

Tags: electrical

I was checking a "dead" outlet for friend. Bottom reads 120volts on hot to ground but top receptacle reads 50 volts hot to ground until the wall switch is flipped then it reads 120volts. Whiskey tango??

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't that be Whiskey Tango Foxtrot? But I digress.

Anyway, I believe you are reading a static induced voltage that your very sensitive digital multi-meter is picking up.

If you were to test that with a solenoid voltage tester or maybe even a lamp tester I believe it will drop to zero. In other words, you meter does not put enough of a load on the test points to drag it down to zero.

Good luck!